# How to pass multiple data in single tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Hello I have two different array data that I need to pass into view controller, my ViewControllers design is the same but the only difference is the data. how can I do that? this is my code

```
var attendance: [GAttendance]!
var subjectAttendances: [GAttendances]!

// In my A controller
let detailAbsenceVC                 = DetailAbsenceVC()
detailAbsenceVC.attendance      = attendances
self.present(detailAbsenceVC, animated: true)

// In my B controller
let detailVC                    = DetailAbsenceVC()
detailVC.subjectAttendances = subjectAttendances
self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return attendance.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GStudentAbsenceCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! GStudentAbsenceCell
    let attendanceItem = attendance[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(attendance: attendanceItem)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: So the `tableView` is located in the `DetailAbsenceVC`, and there you want to display _either_ the `attendance` or the `subjectAttendances` data from the A/B controller?

Comment: yes @AndreasOetjen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not distinguish whether you came from A or B, you just need one arrayto store the data in the `DetailAbsenceVC`, lets call it `detailData`:

```
class DetailAbsenceVC : UIViewController {
    var detailData = [GAttendance]()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return detailData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GStudentAbsenceCell.cellID, for: indexPath) as! GStudentAbsenceCell
        let attendanceItem = detailData[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(attendance: attendanceItem)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Then, in the A/B controller, just set the `detailData`:

```
// In my A controller
let detailAbsenceVC         = DetailAbsenceVC()
detailAbsenceVC.detailData  = attendances
self.present(detailAbsenceVC, animated: true)

// In my B controller
let detailVC        = DetailAbsenceVC()
detailVC.detailData = subjectAttendances
self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: hey thank you @AndreasOetjen it work flawlessly, I was thinking with complicated thing, but the solution so simple. thank you :)